# PHP generation time statistics (fast/slow)

Tags: php, performance, time

I would like to know if the generation time of my PHP page which takes 1sec is fast knowing that this page could be visited by 1000 users at the same time.

My page is composed by :
- 6 SQL queries stored in arrays (it's about 6000 records)
- 1 JSON file of 50kb parsed localy (for the moment)

I generate my php page on my local PC with WampServer 2.0 and my PC is an i7 930 2.8 GHZ with 6GB RAM but in the future i would put my PHP Page on a WebServer from a hosting company, which will be less powerfull i guess ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is php taking 1 second or is the time to rendered page after a request 1 second?

Comment: i use the microtime function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page does get 1000 simultaneous users, and assuming your running mysql and your max connections is 100. You may run out of connections very quickly and some visitors will get the nasty 'mysql server has gone away' or 'too many connections' error.

Are you using any form of caching? If not you should. You could cache the entire output (or as much of the backend processing and output as you can) and store it to disk so you can just fetch and serve a static file. You can also use memcache or just optimize your queries.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, i found some docs on PHP caching. This is right what i'm looking at since the majority of my queries returns the same datas. Any suggestions or good tutorials for caching ? Thx

Comment: Depends what kind of caching you are thinking about. Search for tutorials and you'll find plenty. Or you could make your own home brew cacher of data. For example you could make a utility class that cached data into a json file so you could read it back instead of perform sql queries if the cache hasn't expired yet. There's tons of ways to do it. All of which will accomplish the task and show performance gains. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Less powerful? Probably not. Servers will have multiples of what your localhost system specs are... then again, they also host multiple sites. Your local environment only uses so much resources anyways, so all that processing power doesn't matter.

Each "thread" (or web visit instance) is spawned from the web server (Apache). 1000 users * 6 queries is nothing, even if they all visited at once, the load time would be minimal.

Comment: Ok it reassures me that they are more powerfull. Otherwise, is 1sec fast or slow for that kind of content ? (parsing, queries)

Comment: A page load time of under 3-4 seconds is optimal. After that, visitor retention drops.